# What functions is this?

Tags: special-functions

Good day everyone.

I've encountered a rather strange function while looking up the asymptotic expansion of the confluent hyper geometric function in the NIST Handbook of Mathematical functions.

[image]

Does anyone know what "env" means? Thanks!

Comment: Does not the book explain before the word "env" ?

Comment: See the [envelope function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.8#E33) applied to $Y_{\nu}$.

Comment: @tolaso the nist handbook did not say what function it is. I think it assumes the reader already knows

Comment: @raymond manzoni thanks!

Comment: Could you give the URL of the NIST page you mention ?

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Nice to see you again...

Comment: Glad it helped PhilCsar (and note that the definition depends of the value). Nice to see you too @JeanMarie (I'm rather quiet on the math. side these days but...). Cheers,

Comment: @JeanMarie http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.8